# Magento Load Balancing - additional license

Tags: magento, licensing, load-balancing, enterprise

I already have a Magento Enterprise license for my website. I am planning to expand the infrastructure and introduce another WebApp server. These 2 webApp servers would be managed through a load-balancer.
My question is that in order to add another webapp / frontend server, should I go in for a Enterprise License (complete with production + non-production server) or should I just buy an Additional Production License?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3):

If you're load-balancing, you're going to want the additional license to be the for the same platform as your existing license, because the point of load-balancers is to divide the work between multiple identical systems.

If you don't already have dependence on other Magento Enterprise Edition features, I would recommend against getting an Enterprise license if you are considering load-balancing. Because of the way Magento is licensed, you would require an additional Enterprise Edition license for each installation of Magento, and that includes each instance behind a load-balancer.

If you are considering expanding your infrastructure to include multiple instances of Magento, it is probably best to contact a Magento sales rep, as they will have more-specific information about licensing restrictions, and may be able to negotiate a package which suits your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider vertical scaling before horizontal - you can simply just get *better hardware* rather than making things more complex (and thus prone to error), by introducing more systems.

Typically, for our EE customers, we advocate single-server configurations (obviously, heavily dependant on store details) so that the licensing fee is bypassed. There are a number of other advantages to this too (faster DB access, less complexity, less cost, more secure).

Just consider your reasons for adding another web server - with proper advice and consultancy from a professional - you'll probably find that just adding more servers isn't what you need.

Comment: vertical scaling is always more limited than the horizontal one.  Moreover, on the virtualised platform you can scale up/down horizontally with no pain at all (just add/remove nodes), while the vertical scaling almost always involve taking the corresponding node offline.  Also, your response does not address the original question at all. :(

Comment: That's obvious, but I said scale vertically *before* horizontally, not to avoid horizontal scaling altogether. Unless the OP has significant experience with overseeing multiple machines simultaneously, handling automation and replication - then multi-machine management is a lot more complex than a single machine. The management/monitoring time involved is significantly higher, along with the increased potential of failure. In addition, with the licensing model of EE, its *significantly* cheaper to scale vertically, than horizontally.

Comment: You would be foolish to believe that you can "just add and remove nodes" and expect to be able to scale. Scaling is about resolving bottlenecks, not blindly adding more hardware. You could just as easily cause more problems "adding more nodes" than fix them. Vertical scaling is absolutely a long-term decision, but that would be the case for any business, so the 3 minutes of downtime during an upgrade is irrelevant. NB. You can scale vertically without any downtime if your OS supports it - we do it on a very regular basis, just by live migrating from one piece of hardware to another.